# How to blur the entire background image in css3?

Tags: html, css

```
body
{
background-image:url("hamburger.jpg"),url("glitter.png");
background-blend-mode:color-dodge;
filter:blur(5px);
}
```

I've added two background images,a main jpg image and another png image with glitter effect. I'm trying to blend them using color-dodge, but the glitter dominates. Also,I need to blur the glittering? I tried blurring the image, but only the text gets blurred.

[image: this is how it looks like. I want to blur the glittering?]

Comment: can you provide a couple of screenshots to show what you did and what you are trying to do?

Comment: i've added the image. please refer

Comment: Sorry, I can't see it, are you sure you uploaded those images?

Comment: click on the last link(blue text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm totally getting what you want to achieve here. Yes, you can stack one background-image over the other, either by making use of two separate elements or with the help of a pseudo-element.

With that being said, you won't be able to bring about the effect you are looking for. Why? Because on blurring the image, you are blurring the whole image, not the specific sparkle particles present in the bitmap (there is no way you could do that). Blurring of the whole image creates a misty-kinda effect and I guess it is not what you might be looking for.

I played a bit with some images, stacked them up one over the other, adjusted opacity and filter, and below is what I came up with; see if that helps.

```css
.effect {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/700/400?image=411");
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.effect:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/spoonflower/public/design_thumbnails/0249/0963/rrrrSparkle_silver_mirror.png") 0 0 no-repeat / cover;
  content: "";
  filter: blur(3px);
  opacity: .35;
}

.effect-inner {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3000;
}
```

```html
<div class="effect">
  <div class="effect-inner">
    <h2>CSS is fun!</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are looking for more, you definitely need a JavaScript solution as CSS is not going to help much here.

Comment: Good luck with that! Feel free to vote up the answers which you found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify which language you want, JavaScript, CSS or HTML. For CSS you want the code in, but for CSS just type in:

```
.Background Image {
  filter: blur(20px);
}
```

That is way easier. But if you are using color blend, then you will need to blur the bigger image

You can also do many other things with filer, for example you can edit the contrast and shadow. If you want to learn more about filter go to this website:
[Learn More](http://[https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/][1]%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/)

If you are asking about HTML or JavaScript, then comment, becouse you didn't write it in the "question's description".

Comment: I want it in html. This filter blurs the entire webpage and not just the background image.